# Heroku Deployment Error: displaying backend, not frontend

Tags: heroku, deployment, mern

I am trying to deploy my local MERN application to Heroku. Application works offline. After deployment, when click "Open app", all I see is the data from the backend. Not the front end. Deployment here: https://whispering-falls-45660.herokuapp.com/.

Set up new Heroku project, and after successful "git push Heroku master", application only shows backend data. Heroku CLI version: heroku/7.24.1, Node version: v10.13.0.

Github repo: https://github.com/neilhsieh/whereToEat

Package.json file has the proper scripts in place as per Brad Traversy:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node server.js",
  "server": "nodemon server.js",
  "client": "npm start --prefix client",
  "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
  "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
},
```

server.js code has appropriate code to point to client build file:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('client/build'))

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html')) // relative path
  })
}
```

Expecting front end deployed on Heroku, ended up only having backend.

**UPDATE**: Moved process.env.NODE_ENV test to before all API calls, this fixed my issue.

Comment: Do you have an index.html file committed to the repo? Can you check your gitignore file to make sure all the files are there?

Comment: @MaviDomates, just checked and the index.html is in my git repo under client/public/index.html.
My gitignore file for my server has the following:
node_modules,
package-lock.json

Answer (score 1):

1. First if you have a route like this in your server/app.js file

   `app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("Api Running"))`;

   **Definitely get rid of that**
2. Second add these lines in your `server/app.js` file

   ```
   const path = require("path");

   if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {

       app.use(express.static("client/build"));

       app.get("*", (req, res) => {

       res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));

      });

   }
   ```